# How to align this bootstrap radio button?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[PAGE IS HERE](http://www.thetamilonlinemarket.com/riffaz/dform.html)

I created radio button using following code and the button & the text comes next to each other. That's fine but it is not VERTICALLY middle aligned to the text input field which is placed left to the radio button.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div id="edit-donation-frequent" class="form-radios form-group">
        <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-donation-frequent">
            <input type="radio" id="edit-donation-frequent-monthly" name="donation_frequent" value="monthly" class="form-radio" />  
            <label class="option font-size-sixteen" for="edit-donation-frequent-monthly">Monthly</label>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-donation-frequent form-group">
        <input type="radio" id="edit-donation-frequent-once" name="donation_frequent" value="once" class="form-radio" />  
        <label class="option font-size-sixteen" for="edit-donation-frequent-once">One time </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

[PAGE IS HERE](http://www.thetamilonlinemarket.com/riffaz/dform.html)

I put `.form-item label.option { vertical-align: middle; }` but still the same result.
Then I tried margin-top and some other css styles but could not get what I want.

I want the both radio buttons(monthly, onetime AND Landline) look like following screenshot. 
[image]

and

[image]

how can I adjust the page like screen shots.

**[UPDATE]**

Code for the section (row) as per Rachel's request (Anyhow by visiting [this page](http://www.thetamilonlinemarket.com/riffaz/dform.html) you can have a look at the source code):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-donation-amount form-group">
            <input type="text" id="edit-donation-amount" name="donation_amount" value="" maxlength="128" class="form-text form-control" placeholder="Amount"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-donation-currency form-group">
            <select id="edit-donation-currency" name="donation_currency" class="form-select form-control">
                <option value="DKK">DKK</option>
                <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
                <option value="USD">USD</option>
                <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div id="edit-donation-frequent" class="form-radios form-group">
            <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-donation-frequent">
                <input type="radio" id="edit-donation-frequent-monthly" name="donation_frequent" value="monthly" class="form-radio" />  
                <label class="option font-size-sixteen" for="edit-donation-frequent-monthly">Monthly</label>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-donation-frequent form-group">
            <input type="radio" id="edit-donation-frequent-once" name="donation_frequent" value="once" class="form-radio" />  
            <label class="option font-size-sixteen" for="edit-donation-frequent-once">One time </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide code for the inputs near the radios?

Comment: @RachelS you can have a look at my updated code

Comment: @FoolishCoder linking to your site is pointless. Whilst it may help right now, it'll serve no purpose whatsoever to future visitors of this question when your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, firstly you need to put the surrounding div around the Land line element like you do with the monthly/one time fields and also make the wrappers for the monthly/one time so they are the same

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-donation-amount form-group">
    <input type="text" id="edit-donation-amount" name="donation_amount" value="" maxlength="128" class="form-text form-control" placeholder="Amount">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-donation-currency form-group">
    <select id="edit-donation-currency" name="donation_currency" class="form-select form-control">
      <option value="DKK">DKK</option>
      <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
      <option value="USD">USD</option>
      <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div id="edit-donation-frequent" class="form-radios form-group">
            <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-donation-frequent">
            <input type="radio" id="edit-donation-frequent-monthly" name="donation_frequent" value="monthly" class="form-radio">  
            <label class="option font-size-sixteen" for="edit-donation-frequent-monthly">Monthly</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
  <div id="" class="form-radios form-group">
        <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-donation-frequent form-group">
        <input type="radio" id="edit-donation-frequent-once" name="donation_frequent" value="once" class="form-radio">  
        <label class="option font-size-sixteen" for="edit-donation-frequent-once">One time </label>
        </div>
</div>
        </div>
```

and

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-donation-frequent form-group">
    <input type="radio" id="edit-donation-land-line" name="landline" value="landline" class="form-radio">  
    <label class="option font-size-sixteen" for="edit-donation-land-line">Land Line</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then create a new css rule

```
.form-item.form-type-radio {
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

and this should fix your issues.
Hope that helps